# Filter to show "null" relations (where no results related to the item)

Tags: django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-actions

Quite simply, django filter (standard) give you the option to see "All". I want to create an option to show items which contain "None"

The query would be something like this:

```
tags = Product.objects.exclude(tag__isnull=True)
```

My models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ("Name", max_length=400)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

How would I achieve this? I tried a SimpleListFilter, however this just listed all the items in a filter. I want the items to show up in the admin page view. Can an Admin action do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured it out- Django does this automatically using "list_filter". But it only works if you use the tag (self name as defined in models.py), and not the way I had it as below.

All I had to do was change

```
list_filter: ('tag__name')
```

to

```
list_filter: ('tag')
```

That is the stock method of showing Django filters. It allows me to see All & (none)

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude all  which has no tag as :

```
tags = Product.objects.all().exclude(tag=None)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I achieve this using a an admin action? SimpleListFilter wouldnt work?